# Can a neck strap be attached to Nikon 80-400mm?

Tags: lens, nikon, telephoto

I saw somewhere that a large and heavy telephoto lens had an attachment for a neck strap, that replaces the neck strap for the camera body.

It was, I think, a Nikon 200-400mm lens. But I'm not sure.

In all cases, is there an attachment like this on a Nikon80-400mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often attach a strap to the tripod collar on my larger lenses.  For this I use those oversized idiot straps and just make a girth hitch through the threaded hole where you normally attach to a tripod.

I think it's great alternative to buying a dedicated collar which is going to be way overpriced.

Comment: +1. Good alternative. So the collars shipped with 200-400mm or 80-400mm don't have those attachments for neck strap?